# How to add Get or POST request in the following code

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai

How to add Get or POST request in the following code. My code is running fine. However, how can i add request like GET, POST, PUT OR DELETE

```
var expect  = require('chai').expect;
    var request = require('request');

    describe('Status and content', function() {
        describe ('Main page', function() {
            it('status', function(done){
                request('http://localhost:3000/', function(error, response, body) {
                    expect(response.statusCode).to.equal(200);
                    done();
                });
            });

            it('content', function(done) {
                request('http://localhost:3000/' , function(error, response, body) {
                    //expect(body).to.equal('Hello World');
                    done();
                });
            });
        });

        describe ('About page', function() {
            it('status', function(done){
                request('http://localhost:3000/', function(error, response, body) {
                    expect(response.statusCode).to.equal(200);
                    done();
                });
            });

        });
    });
```

Also, before running this code how i can install and run the JSON server so the api is ready on the localhost. So i do not have to manually do it. 
https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/create-a-rest-api-with-json-server-36da8680136d?fbclid=IwAR2mEtB6-BKAsSgUto3aOTjx8WmAbsfKB6RkSvHeZbI4Jt0fiqMwbV_QvGw

Comment: Where do you want to put them and what do you want to use them for?

Comment: sorry i have updated my question

Comment: Use `chai-http`

Answer (score 0):

You can use request module in this way.

```
let options = {};
options.method = 'GET';   
options.uri = 'http://localhost:3000/';

request(options, function(err, res, body){
//....
});
```

Also for 'POST',

```
let options = {};
options.method = 'POST';
options.uri = 'http://localhost:3000/';
options.body = {payload};
options.headers = {}; //headers if any

request(options, function(err, res, body) {
//.....
});
```